# Limiting results with the SQL:2008 standard on PostgreSQL using prepared statements

Tags: database, postgresql, jdbc, prepared-statement, limit

While working on an example to test the PostgreSQL support for SQL:2008 result set limiting feature, I realized that this syntax doesn't work with a prepared statement:

```
SELECT pc.id AS pc_id, p.id AS p_id  
FROM post_comment pc 
INNER JOIN post p ON p.id = pc.post_id 
ORDER BY pc.id 
OFFSET ? ROWS 
FETCH FIRST ? ROWS ONLY;
```

While for static statements using literals it's just fine, using a prepared statement throws:

> org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "$2"
>   Position: 140     at
>   org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2182)
>   ~[postgresql-9.4-1202-jdbc41.jar:9.4]     at
>   org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1911)
>   ~[postgresql-9.4-1202-jdbc41.jar:9.4]     at
>   org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:173)
>   ~[postgresql-9.4-1202-jdbc41.jar:9.4]     at
>   org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:615)
>   ~[postgresql-9.4-1202-jdbc41.jar:9.4]     at
>   org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeWithFlags(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:465)
>   ~[postgresql-9.4-1202-jdbc41.jar:9.4]     at
>   org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:458)
>   ~[postgresql-9.4-1202-jdbc41.jar:9.4]

If the SQL query is changed to:

```
SELECT pc.id AS pc_id, p.id AS p_id  
FROM post_comment pc 
INNER JOIN post p ON p.id = pc.post_id 
ORDER BY pc.id 
OFFSET ? ROWS 
FETCH FIRST (?) ROWS ONLY;
```

the parenthesis seem to do the trick and the bind parameter is taken into consideration.

Is this a bug or just an implementation detail?

The test is available on [GitHub](https://github.com/vladmihalcea/hibernate-master-class/blob/master/core/src/test/java/com/vladmihalcea/book/high_performance_java_persistence/jdbc/fetching/SQLStandardResultSetLimitTest.java)

Comment: I think this is because `?` is a JSON operator and incorrectly treated by the JDBC driver: http://postgresql.nabble.com/problem-with-pgjdbc-prepared-statements-and-new-jsonb-exists-operator-tp5834634.html

Comment: It's interesting because for OFFSET it works just fine. Only the FETCH directive is affected but this issue.

Comment: I love questions where all the code and information required is right there. Thanks.

Comment: Mea cupla...the first code example shouldn't have the parenthesis around the second bind parameter place holder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TL;DR: Implementation detail.

---

It's not a JDBC driver issue, it's database level.

```
test=> SELECT 1 OFFSET 1 ROWS FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY;
 ?column? 
----------
(0 rows)

test=> PREPARE stmt(integer, integer) AS SELECT 1 OFFSET $1 ROWS FETCH FIRST $2 ROWS ONLY;
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "$2"
LINE 1: ..., integer) AS SELECT 1 OFFSET $1 ROWS FETCH FIRST $2 ROWS ON...
```

The issue is that the argument to `FETCH FIRST n ROWS ONLY` is not being parsed as a literal that's a candidate for parameter placement.

In `src/backend/parser/gram.y`:

```
          /* SQL:2008 syntax */
          | FETCH first_or_next opt_select_fetch_first_value row_or_rows ONLY
              { $$ = $3; }
```

and

```
  /*                          
   * Allowing full expressions without parentheses causes various parsing
   * problems with the trailing ROW/ROWS key words.  SQL only calls for
   * constants, so we allow the rest only with parentheses.  If omitted,
   * default to 1.
   */
  opt_select_fetch_first_value:
              SignedIconst                        { $$ = makeIntConst($1, @1); }
              | '(' a_expr ')'                    { $$ = $2; }
              | /*EMPTY*/                         { $$ = makeIntConst(1, -1); }
          ;
```

shows that this is in fact intentional, and that the parentheses are required to remove ambiguity for parameter use, but SQL:2008 doesn't require this to be supported as a query parameter anyway.

If you want to supply a parameter, use parentheses.

Comment: Thanks for such a detailed explanation, this kind of info is impossible to get unless you really know what happens behind the scenes. Just by chance I tried with parenthesis and it worked out. I couldn't find any warning in the reference documentation, so I think it's worth adding a paragraph about this in the PostgreSQL manual, right?

Comment: @VladMihalcea Yes, definitely. Please file a bug report (http://www.postgresql.org/support/submitbug/) or the pgsql-docs mailing list. I'll try to follow up on it, but it'd be very helpful if you could send in a report as I tend to lose track of things (lots and lots to do).

Comment: Sure, the bug report #13639. Thanks for all the help.